# Вытащить из jsp url

Tags: java, jsp, xmlhttprequest

Как можно узнать из jsp, кто запустил во фрейме, не клиент, а какой сервер, его url или ip, если запустили jsp во фрейме?

Comment: jsp это тот же сервлет
`HttpServletRequest.getLocalAddr()` должен вернуть ip сервера

Comment: @whispeer моя страница запускается фреймом, надо узнать адрес того, который его запустил, не клиента, а какой сервер поставил мою страницу во фрейм, эта команда возвращает айпи клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTTP для такого предусмотрен заголовок запроса **referer**.
Подробнее [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Comment: Также наверное request.getRemoteAddr() должно помочь.